# Anime or movie about a girl escaping a world that's blown up

Tags: story-identification, anime

I can remember watching this in the late 90s, but it could be older. A young girl is put into a shuttle, as her world or space station is being blasted apart. She's blonde I think, and you see the station/planet explode as her pod flies away. I really can't remember any more, but it's very vivid. I know this isn't much to go on, but any help would be greatly appreciated. I think it was a film, and was around the same period as the Ewoks cartoon, although I think this was Japanese, and was actually a proper anime.

Comment: Do you know if this was the beginning of the movie/series?

Comment: Sounds a lot like Supergirl being sent from Krypton to Earth.  Was there a Supergirl movie prior to the late '90s?

Comment: There was a piece of crap in 1984 staring Helen Slater and Peter O'Toole.

Comment: It was definitely the big inning of the movie/series